# Style Just One Tab in Bootstrap Nav Tab

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a nav tab using Bootstrap 3, and want to style just one tab.  Not the acive tab, or inactive tab; I have a single tab that I have applied the class "csv-download" to.  I want to update this particular tab to remove the border and make the background transparent.

The reason I am doing this is that I want the download link to be aligned properly with the other tabs, and to also be responsive for smaller screens.

Here is the setup for my tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" i>
    <li class="active" role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#link1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#link2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#link3">Tab 3</a></li>

    <li id="dfw_download" class="csv-download"><a target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-download"></i>  Download Data</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here are the seperate things I've tried:

```
.csv-download a {

    background-color: transparent;
    color: #0277bd;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And:

```
.nav-tabs > li > .csv-download > a {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #0277bd;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you just assign an id to that tab?

Comment: You  don't have to add a unique class or identifier to the last `li` element if the `li` you want to style uniquely is the last one in `ul`. You can simply use `li:last-child`, and then apply your CSS rules. And just like the last `li` in a list, you can also select the first `li` in a list by using `li:first-child`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For override the default style bootstrap uses on they elements:

**1)** You can use the `!important` (**non-recommended**) sentence on the CSS.

Or

**2)** Create your own custom style class and apply they on the element you want to style.

Check next example:

```css
.csv-download a {

    background-color: red !important;
    color: black !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.custom-link > a {

    background-color: red;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active" role="presentation">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#link1">Tab 1</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#link2">Tab 2</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#link3">Tab 3</a>
      </li>
      <li id="dfw_download" class="csv-download">
        <a target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download Data</a>
      </li>
      <li id="dfw_download" class="csv-download custom-link">
        <a target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download Data</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Using `!important` is a horrible idea, with frontend and UI/UX developers widely misusing it. CSS is all about cascading and hierarchy. I suggest properly selecting with priorities to add your overrides.

Comment: It could be horrible idea, i have to say never had to use it, but for some  particular cases could be needed. I have update with the alternative I use mostly of the time.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess a few things to consider here. The appropriate way to handle this is to simply have a higher CSS specificity than what bootstrap is providing. The core issue that makes this feels icky is you truly don't want to be styling directly on elements if you can help it. [Bootstrap 4 addresses this where they move a majority of their styling to classes i.e. `.nav-item`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/) so you can put more classes on top.

I would highly recommend not using `!important`. Not that it is "wrong" -- there are times when libraries have very high specificity styles (ew) and it sometimes makes sense to force them to know to prefer your styles but if there are other means (which there seems there are), it's preferable to do those instead.

Looking at some of their [old examples from Bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar/), it looks like their examples attempt to override certain styles by using child combinator (`>`) i.e. `.nav > li > a` to override the styles.

It's also worth seeing if Bootstrap 3 provided a way to import specific styles? If there's a way you can only import the styles you need through a Sass/LESS version of Bootstrap, that also could be an option.